# Sum over one level of multiindex in assignment to new column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization

I have a pandas Dataframe, whose columns are

```
cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, value1, value2
```

I would like to add a new column value3 and assing it a value that depends on value1 and the sum of value1 over all values in cat4. Is it possible to do this in a vectorized/efficient way, or do I need to write a for loop?

For example if the values were

```
cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, value1, value2
A,A,A,A, 3,1
A,A,A,B, 5,2
A,A,A,C, 22,4
A,A,X,A, 0,5
A,A,X,B, 4,5
A,A,X,C, 6,5
```

My desired endresult would be

```
cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, value1, value2, value3
A,A,A,A, 3,1, 30
A,A,A,B, 5,2, 30
A,A,A,C, 22,4, 30
A,A,X,A, 0,5, 10
A,A,X,B, 4,5, 10
A,A,X,C, 6,5, 10
```

where value3 is the same sum over the value1 values with different cat4 entries when all entries of cat1, cat2, and cat3 are the same.
Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't the 29 be rather 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) per groups of cat1/cat2/cat3:

```
df['value3'] = (df.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
                ['value1'].transform('sum'))
```

output:

```
  cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4  value1  value2  value3
0    A    A    A    A       3       1      30
1    A    A    A    B       5       2      30
2    A    A    A    C      22       4      30
3    A    A    X    A       0       5      10
4    A    A    X    B       4       5      10
5    A    A    X    C       6       5      10
```